# Using flask-socketio, how can I asynchornously emit multiple messages in one function?

Tags: python, flask, websocket, backend

I'm building a Flask web app using the flask-socketio module to implement websockets. It generally works fine, but when I try to emit multiple messages from the server to the client in a for loop, all the messages are actually sent at once - that is, as soon as all of them have been created.

I read that the solution might be to use an eventlet server capable of asynchronous task handling:

"The simplest deployment strategy is to have eventlet or gevent installed, and start the web server by calling socketio.run(app) as shown in examples above. This will run the application on the eventlet or gevent web servers, whichever is installed." (taken from the Flask-SocketIO docs)

Sadly, that doesn't solve the problem. I've never worked with websockets before, so I'm a bit lost. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

import eventlet

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on("connect")
def handle_connect():
    print("server and client connected")

@socketio.on("text")
def text(question):
    for _ in range(3):
        answer = my_module.generate_answer(question)
        emit("message", {"msg": answer})

socketio.run(app)
```

Just assume that my_module.generate_answer() generates a sentence based on some user input sent via the websocket. Each generation takes 5-10 seconds. That's also the reason why I want the answers to be sent via a WebSocket once they're generated - my frontend could already display the first answer while waiting for the next ones.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to monkey patch at the very top of your file.

Your import statements should look like this:

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()

from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
```